# Creating an encrypted backups for my entire home directory

Tags: backup, encryption

I almost done everything when backup my home directory then store these compression file in file /var/backups ... but in case I want to encrypt that backup It refuse cuz of

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

this is my command

```
tar -zcvf /home/rehab | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 -o 
var/backups/myhome.tar.gz.gpg
```

Comment: There is no such directory as `var`, it should be `/var` perhaps that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

From `tar --help`:

```
-f, --file=ARCHIVE         use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

With your `f` option `tar` is expecting an output file, like foo.tar.gz. So this should work:

```
tar -zcv /home/rehab | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 -o /var/backups/myhome.tar.gz.gpg
```

Mind the `/` in front of `/var`

Comment: yes that almost work but the permission denied when creating in the /var/backups , even in sudo permission, first ask me about the password of gpg then compress file then encrypt all of them but when put that file in folder /var/backups permission denied

Comment: To write in /var you need sudo privileges.

Comment: I write sudo before the command but didn't ask me to enter the sudo password because the window of gpg password displayed in the first , and in root shill the gpg password window didn't display then the output is operation canceled